# Firefox with text-shadow lags, works fine on Chrome/Edge

Tags: css, firefox, lag

I am creating a website and I have an issue with text-shadow and Firefox. There are about 100 div containing text in the background and with the following css:

```
.hex {
    position: absolute;
    user-select: none;
    outline: none;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.2;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(148, 0, 211, 1)
}
```

It work fine even on Edge... but Firefox seems to have an issue with text-shadow; if I disable this rule in fact, it works fine also on Firefox.

By testing a little, it seems that the performance slightly improves on FF when using `filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px rgba(148, 0, 211, 1)`; on the other hand it sucks on Chrome/Edge.

What's the best solution here? Why FF struggles with text-shadow?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: have you tried something about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change , even if it seems off topic, you gave too little infos ? Can also add enough HTML to show your issue ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tests and it seems Firefox won't accept a value with `rgba` in the `text-shadow` property.
You are using opacity 1 in your code so there is no use for it there, try to change it to `text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgb(148, 0, 211)`

Comment: Unfortunately even removing the alpha value the issue remains.

Comment: What is your firefox version? [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I was using the version 69.0.3 (64-bit), now I just updated it and I'm using the version 70.0. Seems a little better but I need to test it more. One of the users reported a 100% cpu usage when on my website. https://sugoi.online/sickdyd